# Merge Sort - This Recursive Implementation Code Works But I Have A Question About "In-Place"

Tags: python, function, recursion, mergesort, in-place

```
1 def merge_sort(arr):
2    
3    if len(arr) > 1:
4        # Divide the array into two halves
5        mid = len(arr) // 2
6        left_half = arr[:mid]
7        right_half = arr[mid:]
8        
9        # Recursively sort the left and right halves
10        a = merge_sort(left_half)
11        b = merge_sort(right_half)
12        
13        print("left:", left_half, a)
14        print("right:", right_half, b)
15
16        # Merge the sorted halves
17        i = j = k = 0
18        while i < len(left_half) and j < len(right_half):
19            
20            if left_half[i] < right_half[j]:
21                arr[k] = left_half[i]
22                i += 1
23            else:
24                arr[k] = right_half[j]
25                j += 1
26            k += 1
27
28        # Check for any remaining elements in the left or right halves
29        while i < len(left_half):
30            arr[k] = left_half[i]
31            i += 1
32            k += 1
33
34        while j < len(right_half):
35            arr[k] = right_half[j]
36            j += 1
37            k += 1
38
39
40    return arr
41
42
43 res = merge_sort([2,3,1,5,6,4])
44 print(res)
```

And the output for the above code is:

```
left: [3] [3]
right: [1] [1]
left: [2] [2]
right: [1, 3] [1, 3]
left: [6] [6]
right: [4] [4]
left: [5] [5]
right: [4, 6] [4, 6]
left: [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
right: [4, 5, 6] [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

.
.

**I have a question specifically regarding this chunk of code:**

```
a = merge_sort(left_half)
b = merge_sort(right_half)
```

It seems to me that without the above assignment (a and b), the code is implicitly doing this:

```
left_half = merge_sort(left_half)
right_half = merge_sort(right_half)
```

I do not understand how this "in-place" modification is done during this recursion process?

Comment: `arr[k] = left_half[i]` This code, and other lines like it, assign to `arr`.  This is how `arr` is modified in-place.

Comment: @JohnGordon I do understand that, maybe let me edit my question to reflect my query in a clearer manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in python arguments are [passed by reference](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference). 
Since you are modifying `arr` directly in your function, it does not matter if you return it or not. 
If you do not want to modify the original array, I suggest you to create a copy of `arr` inside your function and then modify and return that copy.